# How can i download dynamic HTML in automated procedure?

Tags: html, web, web-scraping

Ok, im desperated.. I don't know anything about web technologies, web programing, frameworks and all of this and i need to download **FULL HTML FILE** - with all dynamicaly rendered content (javascript? ajax?..) and i even don't know how to name this..

Please save my life (absolutely frustrated), and show me a few lines of code (any language, command line in windows or simple external software) that will be able to get this done.

In need to do this for few hundred websites, so repeatable and automated procedure is needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In linux terminal you can use program such as curl. There are equivalents in windows.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install curl
curl https://stackoverflow.com/ > file.html
```

or

```
apt-get update
apt-get install wget
wget https://stackoverflow.com/
```

If there is content added to the webpage after loading it, like you say because it executes JavaScript code to download extra data after loading the page, you are better off using a headless brower in Python or something. Search for selenium. This will be a bit of custom programming depending on what exactly you want to do. Login, cookies, click buttons robotically, etc.

Comment: I don't believe it.. THIS REALLY WORKS. FINALY!!! Thank YOU !!!